# How to make appium automation more stable in android?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, mobile, automation, appium

I use `appium` version 7.1.0 for mobile automation.

Sometimes the automation isn't stable - it fails because of waiting time for loading and swiping because of resolution of different screens.

I tried to put `wait` for fixed time and swiping to fixed coordinates of elements.

I would to know how to improve the stability of the automation.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.